# Rocky Linux 8.9 firewall blocks IPv6 mDNS packets from one specific host?

Tags: firewall, rocky-linux, mdns

The local network is running IPv6 and have one server running DHCPv6 / DNS service. It also broadcast mDNS (`_http._tcp`) for some other services.

I've 3 computers connected to the local network, two macOS, and one laptop running Rocky Linux 8.9. The problem is, Rocky Linux can't receive mDNS message *specifically* from that DHCPv6/DNS server.

Its kinda weird because:

1. Avahi-daemon works normally on Rocky Linux: it can hear mDNS messages from both macOS and itself, just not from DHCP/DNS server.
2. Avahi-daemon works normally on DHCP/DNS server: both macOS computers can hear mDNS messages from all 4 hosts.
3. It's firewall related issue: Rocky Linux can hear mDNS messages from all 4 hosts **when the firewall is turned off** (`systemctl stop firewalld`)
4. It's IPv6 related issue: Rocky Linux can also hear mDNS message from all 4 hosts if enabling IPv4 on every host.
5. All 4 computer are connected to **unmanaged** L2 switch so there is no VLAN or anti-multicast stuff.

So the Rocky Linux firewall is blocking mDNS form one specific host, and it's only blocking mDNS in IPv6 mode. But it's running default firewall settings without any change after installation.

Any idea what's going on ? Or what kind of firewall rule should I add so that it receive *ALL* mDNS messages ?